# Can we get stack trace from an exception?

Tags: python

To get stacktrace, I use:

```
except:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exec())
```

Can I get stacktrace from an exception without using traceback? Example:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.traceback) #is there command like this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using the traceback module, we should be able to get some further detail using sys.exc_info. This returns a tuple including traceback info:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    tb = sys.exec_info()[2]
    ...
```

The traceback object has info about the stack frame and line number the error occurred on.

This is what traceback uses under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You need `traceback`. You can use it together with `e`. You should import it at the beginning of your code, you don't need to import it every time an exception occurs.

```
import traceback

try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print(e)
    print(tb)
```

Comment: Why does the exception object not have the stack trace?

Comment: @variable It does: `e.__traceback__`. But as a rule for all `__dunder__` names, these are reserved for internal usage, and your code shouldn't rely on them (they can be changed / removed without deprecation). The `traceback` module is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Traceback Module - More info can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

or save it as a variable first like the following:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    st = traceback.format_stack()
    print(st)
```